# python django intercepting an sql query before it is executed

Tags: python, django

I have a library that natively crashes into django and works with django Admin and knows how to use objects.all() and so on.
The QuerySet  goes  instead of  to the database location in another api project.
I need to intercept an sql query before executing which django does so that I can do even more magic with queries.
maybe someone knows how to do it in theory ? well, or there is an example I will be glad to see.

I tried to look for something similar on the Internet, but everywhere there is information only for outputting information to the logs about executed requests through Middleware

Comment: Django Debug Toolbar intercepts SQL requests. After skimming through the source of this package, I saw it uses a decorator around SQL cursor to achieve this.
You can see how the did it [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/blob/main/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py#L28).

Comment: Have a look at [Database instrumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/instrumentation/) that will allow you to get the SQL query and possibly modify it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.